# Putting data into MySQL using putdatabaserecord in NIFI

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi

I have a flow **Getfile -> PutDatabaseRecord** and I have a CSV with fields as follows :

**Module No, Pos, Machine Name, Machine Type**

I want to ingest the value for these fields in my database table 'Test' that has fields describes as:

**Module_No,Pos,Machine_Name,Machine_Type**

So here is a change in fields name. What setting to set in the Putdatabaserecord to successfully ingest the data into mysql table.

Right now I am getting error as Module No cannot be null. How can I fix this change of header names in the original CSV and MySQL table.
Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PutDatabaseRecord, you can configure your schema to use the field names as they appear in the database, and ignore the header names (which are slightly different). If you are using `Get String Fields From Header` as your Schema Access Strategy, change this to `Use Schema Text` and put the following in the Schema Text property:

```
{
 "namespace": "nifi",
 "name": "machine",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
  {"name": "Module_No","type": "string"},
  {"name": "Pos","type": "string"},
  {"name": "Machine_Name","type": "string"},
  {"name": "Machine_Type","type": "string"}
 ]
}
```

Then set `Treat First Line As Header` to `true` and set `Ignore CSV Header Column Names` to `true`. Then the records will be read in using the explicit field names, which match the columns in your DB, and the processor should work correctly.